# Angular Youtube Player - Fit to 100% height

Tags: css, angular, youtube

I use the [Youtube Angular](https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/youtube-player) pakacge in my Angular 11 project. I would like to fill the player to 100% of the divs height, which is a [TailWind](https://tailwindcss.com/) `h-full` div:

```
<div class="flex flex-col flex-auto w-full h-full xs:p-2" #videoContainer>
    <youtube-player
            *ngIf="videoId"
            [videoId]="videoId"
            width="100%"
            [height]="videoHeight"
    ></youtube-player>
</div>
```

I tried to do this in two different eays already:

#### #1 `height="100%"` or `height="100vh"`

Both leads to:
[image: 100% Height]

#### #2 Dynamic Height

`[height]="videoHeight"`

```
ngOnInit() {

    this._params = this._route.params.subscribe((params) => {
        this.videoId = params['videoId'];
    });

}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.videoHeight = this.videoContainer.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
}
```

This works, but leads to

> Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '905'..

#### #3 Move `videoHeight`

I moved `this.videoHeight = this.videoContainer.nativeElement.offsetHeight;` to the constructor and in the `OnInit` this leads to:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined at new YoutubeComponent

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Has your been resolved?

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I solved it,
I created new component:

`ng g component components/yt-player`

In `yt-player.component.html` add container with ref and `youtube-player`

```html
<div #youTubePlayer >
    <youtube-player [width]="videoWidth" [height]="videoHeight" [videoId]="videoID"></youtube-player>
</div>
```

and in `yt-player.component.ts` add this code:

```
export class YtPlayerComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('youTubePlayer') youTubePlayer: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

  videoHeight: number | undefined;
  videoWidth: number | undefined;

  @Input('videoID') videoID: string;

  constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.onResize();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize.bind(this));
  }

  onResize(): void {
        // you can remove this line if you want to have wider video player than 1200px
    this.videoWidth = Math.min(
      this.youTubePlayer.nativeElement.clientWidth,
      1200
    );
        // so you keep the ratio
    this.videoHeight = this.videoWidth * 0.6;
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

The code is basiclly self explenatory, you have refrence on the container of youtube-player,  in afterViewInit you set `videoHeight` and `videoWidth`, to corespond to the width of the container. We set up event listener in the case of size changes to update the width and height. And in the end we add `@Input('videoID') videoID: string` so we can pass the id to the youtube-player component. So we can use it like this:

`<yt-player videoID="oHg5SJYRHA0"></yt-player>`

Answer (score 0):

1. Try `height="100vh"`
2. Try assigning value to `videoHeight` during declaration or in `constructor`
   or in `ngOnInit` hook.

Comment: I tried it, both does not work, I updated the question accordingly

Comment: Could you reproduce a minimal scenario at stackblitz?

Comment: I am new to Stackblitz, I have a Type Error which I don't have in my IDE, but here you go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-svnhxv?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: the height of angular youtube supports only numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
      <youtube-player
      [videoId]="videoId"
      [width]="screenWidth"
      [height]="screenHeight"
    ></youtube-player>



import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: 'your-component.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['your-component.page.scss'],
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

  screenWidth: number;
  screenHeight: number;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    this.screenHeight = window.innerHeight * 0.3; // 30% of the viewport height
  }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Remove any attempt to set `width` and `height` in the template code -

```html
<div class="flex flex-col flex-auto w-full h-full xs:p-2">
    <youtube-player *ngIf="videoId" [videoId]="videoId"></youtube-player>
</div>
```

and also from the component code. Then it should display automatically to full height.